# I need help to be able to focus during my work outs

Tags: muscle, training, motivation

I stop working out few months ago because of work I travel a lot and I lost a lot of muscle . I got me a membership at a gym but is so hard for me to concentrate and motivate myself while I'm at the gym what can I do to get back at it and be able to concentrate . I was a very active and hard worker person before I stop my work outs

Comment: It´s not motivation which lacks most of the time, it´s dicipline. You don´t have to be super motivated or enthusiastic about your sport, but you have to be strictly with your shedule. Write it a month in advance, plan it fully and then stick to it whatever happens.

Comment: It's not always necessary that if you are going to the gym then you are an active person. Now, there are many [apps for smart-phones](http://blog.defensesoap.com/athletes/healthy-apps-to-help-athletes-stay-healthy-in-2016/) that can help you to stay active even at home and if travel a lot then these are actually helpful. Try them.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this splits into two primary situations: either you're having an issue getting *to* the gym consistently or you're having trouble actually working out once you get there.

### Getting to the gym

This is the more common situation in my experience, and is a major part of the business plan for most gyms. It's hard to wake up early in the morning to exercise before work. After work, you're stressed and tired, and maybe hungry from not having eaten since lunch. If you go home for a bit, the odds are you don't leave...

Now, reading your question, it doesn't seem that's actually the case for you yet, but for me, the key is to simply be there. Schedule your time at the gym. Make it a priority and pick a consistent time. Even if you're not feeling in top shape, even if you'd really prefer to go home and curl up with your computer, go to the gym. Track it on a calendar so that it quickly becomes obvious if you start skipping going.

### Exercising while at the gym

I'm kind of prone to this one myself. I go to the gym and I wind up just sort of faffing about, doing random exercises or taking long breaks in between to "recover" or check my email. My solution has been to have a consistent routine and stick to it. Your gym may have a posted circuit which you can follow. Set your goals and push through them. Set a timer for breaks so that you never spend more than a few minutes, and preferably stay up and moving, walking around, while on break, to keep from tightening up and to keep your bloodflow up.

Comment: To add you to your second point, I'd say that unless you use it to log what you do at the gym or as a source of music, that your phone should stay in the locker room. The fewer the distractions, the better.